# Fastest way to format a list of numbers in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, list

I have a list of order #s w/ several line items; each line item needs to be listed w/a unique # but include original #;  like 1234-1, 1234-2, 1234-3 then 2345-1, 2345-2. Easiest way to do this?

Comment: use countifs in a helper column.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: what is w/a short for ?

Comment: @PeterH "with a"

Answer (score 1):

If your data was in a column starting at `A1`, you could put this formula in `B1`:

```
=A1&"-"&COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)
```

`A$1:A1` is important because the `$` locks the row reference even as you copy down. The formula in `B2` will automatically update to `A$2:A1` and so on. This means the `COUNTIF()` function will always reference every row up until this row, giving you the number of times this value has occurred in the column *so far*.

[image: Screenshot]